# Not able to delete records from table(order) having its id column as foreign key in multiple order tables in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an "**orders**" table
with its id as foreign key in below tables
**dispatch_details**
**order_histories**
**sales_return_details**
**promotion_orders**

While creating the table we haven't added ON DELETE CASCADE.
so I have deleted all the required records from referenced tables i.e. dispatch_details,
order_histories, sales_return_details and promotion_orders.

It's taking way too much time still not able to delete records from orders even though I am not getting any error. It is only processing but doesn't complete.

I have further added index for all the referenced table.

```
create index idx_dispatch_details_order_id on dispatch_details(order_id);
create index idx_order_histories_order_id on order_histories(order_id);
create index idx_sales_return_details_order_id on sales_return_details(order_id);
create index idx_promotion_orders_order_id on promotion_orders(order_id);
```

Still, I am not able to delete the records.

Is there any way to delete the records table from orders efficiently? Currently, I am not able to delete even single records from orders.

Comment: what is the delete query which is taking high time? Also, it will reflect rows deleted once all rows are deleted.

Comment: Are you trying to delete all of them or just some specific orders? Use truncate in case you want to delete all. About taking long time, delete usually perform a record inside log file, if the log file is too huge, it will take a long time. You can take a database log backup before perform the delete.

Comment: I suspect you have some sort of complicated trigger.

Comment: I have used below query:
delete from orders
where call_id in (select id from calls
    where daily_orders_info_id in (select id from daily_orders_info where date < '2020-07-18'));
And added index for both id of calls and id of daily_orders_info.
There is not any trigger associated with any tables.

Can't use truncate tables. Need to delete records of certain fiscal year data only

Answer (score 0):

I have further added an index to all table calls and daily_order_info table. Also, the orders table has parent_order_id FK reference to itself. Added index for that column as well. Basically, for all the tables referenced: created an index and that solved my issue.